# Xamarin Android error on DeviceInfo.Model

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.essentials

I have a `Xamarin` for Android app that has been working until today.  I needed to make a change but before I did, I ran a test to ensure no VS or Nuget package updates caused an issue.  I have `Xamarin.Essentials` in my app and this line worked before, not sure what is happening now.

```
if(DeviceInfo.Model == "TC72"){scannerIndex = 1;}
```

Exception Unhandled:

> Xamarin.Essentials.NotImplementedInReferenceAssemblyException: 'This
> functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this
> assembly. You should reference the NuGet package from your main
> application project in order to reference the platform-specific
> implementation.'

Any insight would be helpful.  TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the DeviceInfo.Model to Build.Model and get the same info I was expecting.  That fixed my issue.  If anyone has a different suggestion, happy to entertain them.

Added 8/11/21 3:25pm CT
I also found that changing my Compile Target to 10.0 fixed the Xamarin.Essentials issues.  So far the application is working on 8.1 on the device (Zebra MC3300).